# curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: Network is unreachable

Tags: python, curl, tornado

I get the above error when I type `curl http://localhost:8000/` in the terminal to run a python/tornado script.

My curl version is 7.19.7. I have IPV6 disabled.

My /etc/hosts reads

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   aniruddha-laptop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Output of `lsof | grep 8000`

```
dbus-daem  1338  aniruddha   67u     unix 0xf2208000      0t0       8923 socket
gconfd-2   1341  aniruddha   20u     unix 0xf2ab8000      0t0       7180 socket
trashappl  1468  aniruddha   18u     unix 0xf4248000      0t0       8689 socket
notificat  1478  aniruddha   14u     unix 0xf20a8000      0t0       8613 socket
```

Comment: what is in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: As a test - what happens if you try curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ?

Comment: @JonClements curl 127.0.0.1:8000 <HTML><TITLE>503 Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<H1>503 Service Unavailable</H1>
Failed to connect to server <B>127.0.0.1</B><

Comment: @Aniruddha And do you get the same if you just try via a web browser? The ::1 indicates something to do with IPv6 but a 503 indicates something else...

Comment: @BurhanKhalid                                               '127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 aniruddha-laptop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts'

Comment: @JonClements Same result when I try in browser, `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: @AniruddhaJana I s'pose just make sure what you're trying to connect to is actually running. Sorry - system config. troubleshooting isn't my area - hopefully someone will pick this up from the tornado tag - or add a couple of system configuration web server tags...

Comment: You are on linux? What is `lsof | grep 8000` output?

Comment: @NikolayFominyh I am on Ubuntu 10.04  Output of `lsof | grep 8000`                                                                                                      `dbus-daem  1338  aniruddha   67u     unix 0xf2208000      0t0       8923 socket  
gconfd-2   1341  aniruddha   20u     unix 0xf2ab8000      0t0       7180 socket  
trashappl  1468  aniruddha   18u     unix 0xf4248000      0t0       8689 socket  
notificat  1478  aniruddha   14u     unix 0xf20a8000      0t0       8613 socket`

Comment: @NikolayFominyh I have edited my question to include the output of `lsof | grep 8000`

Comment: @JonClements The program runs on `localhost:8000/`

Comment: @AniruddhaJana it looks, that tornado is not running on 8000 port. Also try `lsof | grep <your_app_name>` to get port on which tornado running. If it's not running - tell us how you start tornado and what is output on startup.

Comment: This isn't specific to software development; it should be at [unix.se] rather than here.

Answer (score -1):

Do `cat /etc/resolv.conf` you will find `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, then you should move this entry and add any available nameserver.

Comment: "localhost" was already successfully resolved to `::1` before the error took place. This is not a DNS problem, except insofar as the OP has `::1` listed in `/etc/hosts` without also having a working IPv6 stack -- but `/etc/hosts` takes priority over external DNS servers, so changing what's in `resolv.conf` won't change lookup results.

Comment: Moreover, this question isn't "unique to software development" as required to be on topic here, and off-topic questions shouldn't be answered -- see the Answer Well-Asked Questions section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).